# What is the meaning of "interesting" in a mathematical context? Does it have an abstract mathematical model?

Tags: mathematical-modeling, philosophy

I, from time to time, see the word "interesting" in a mathematical context when models are explained, and I realized that there is actually a philosophical depth to that.

- Is there a philosophical definition of what makes a mathematical model or mathematical finding interesting?
- Does "interesting" have an abstract mathematical model? (in category theory perhaps?)

Comment: Maybe one could interpret the meaning of a modal operator in *modal logic* to be 'interesting' and make up some models to illustrate it.

Comment: an interesting idea. in this sense, maybe "interesting" could be the amount of modal operators  that are using the object along with their qualitative multipliers (utility of models in life? page rank of models using modal operators as their connections? ...), as means of a metric giving as a comparison between two objects to order them by how interesting they are.
but well, i still wonder if we are in the correct direction : )
i think somebody should have worked on this subject before, i feel it

Comment: Perhaps you should edit your thoughts into the question, using the [edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3455904/edit) button under the question. That said, I suspect that your vague beginnings of a definition of "interesting" are arbitrary and I doubt that this has been investigated in the way you suggest. Perhaps an expert in mathematical logic, category theory or some other area might be able to say more.

Comment: I also wonder about the appropriateness of the tag (mathematical-modeling), as I think it is meant more in the applied mathematics sense. You might consider tags such as (model-theory) and/or (category-theory). You can change the tags when you edit your question.

Comment: I am thinking on this for a while, when i asked this question i thought there would be one definition of simple definition of "interesting" in mathematical context. I'm not sure if it will make sense to change it into "can it be defined", because that would be asking people to do something that wasn't done before, like asking somebody to write a paper on an unknown area as a stackoverflow question (1)

Comment: I could change the labels as you suggest, but i am not sure if it will lead anywhere. i think the question is just stuck, and maybe the answers is just "no, there is no certain definition of interesting in math, the way it is used is just how you would use it in simple english" (2)

Comment: You are probably correct. Maybe someone will (re)discover this question one day and provide an answer (different from my Tao reference).

Comment: The following soft question on MathOverflow may also be worth checking out: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/348423/modeling-in-pure-math

Answer (score 2):

Terence Tao wrote an article entitled ["What is Good Mathematics?"](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0702396.pdf) that may provide you with some food for thought. Whether it answers your question or not is hard to say. Personally, I think that something being interesting is highly subjective. In any case, here are the opening sentences from Tao's article. Please see the link above for the whole piece.

> We all agree that mathematicians should strive to produce good mathematics. But
> how does one define “good mathematics”, and should one even dare to try at all? Let
> us first consider the former question. Almost immediately one realises that there are
> many different types of mathematics which could be designated “good”. For instance,
> “good mathematics” could refer (in no particular order) to
>
> (i) Good mathematical problem-solving (e.g. a major breakthrough on an important mathematical problem);
>
> (ii) Good mathematical technique (e.g. a masterful use of existing methods, or the
> development of new tools);

Another thought on interesting mathematics comes from Richard Brown's TEDx talk [Why mathematics?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kg2mOl042ng), in which he defines "interesting" roughly as "hard, but worthy of study".